# Ubuntu 20.04 boot message

Tags: boot

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on my Dell laptop. The system all the sudden started displaying large amount of boot messages when starting up. I edited ./etc/default/grub file to modify the lines below.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet"
```

This suppressed almost all the boot messages,except now I get a string of text below before starting up.

[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^

Any idea what this means?

Answer (score 0):

During your edit of /etc/default/grub, you may have accidentally added some garbage text into the file. Review the file closely.

You've obviously modified this file more than once.

Change the following lines back to default...

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

then `sudo update-grub`

**Update #1:**

Turns out that the DELETE key on the keyboard gets stuck.

Comment: heynnerma, thank you. I did a bit more trouble shooting. According to Wikipedia, the string of characters showing up on the screen is the escape sequence for the Delete key, ^[[3~.   And the Delete key on my laptop recently started having problem, alternating between being non-responsive to deleting half page of text. I wonder if the Delete key being engaged during the boot causing the system to display the boot messages in the first place.

Comment: @yorkville Ah! A bad keyboard. Time to replace it.

Comment: @yorkville Status please...

Comment: I am working on replacing the keyboard as its the likely culprit of the boot message. Keyboard replacement requires the removal of the motherboard. And the motherboard happens to have one stripped screw holding it down. Still working on it.

Comment: @yorkville Are you sure that the motherboard has to come out to change the keyboard? Many times the keyboard has just a couple of screws holding it in from the bottom. Other times the top half of the case needs to be removed. And once and a while, the keyboard can be removed by releasing some catches up near the number keys. See if YouTube has a video for you.